# Como eu busco a informação deste autocomplete

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="/template/template_#{loginControle.usuarioLogado.tipo}.xhtml" >
        <ui:define name="conteudo">

            <f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function valorPeca() {
                            var valorpeca = document.getElementById("f1:valorPeca");     
                            alert(valorpeca);
                        }

                </script>  

                <h:form acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1" id="f1">
                    <p:growl id="growlMessages"/>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                            <h:outputText value="Manutenção de Chamado"/>
                        </f:facet>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Código:" for="id" />
                        <p:inputText size="4" disabled="true" id="id" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.id}" title="Código do Chamado" />

                        <p:commandLink id="pessoa1" value="Cliente:" ajax="true" /> 
                        <p:autoComplete id="pessoa" style="width:600px" dropdown="true"
                                        multiple="false" forceSelection="true" var="obj"
                                        itemLabel="#{obj.nome}" itemValue="#{obj}"
                                        value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.pessoa}"
                                        converter="#{chamadoControle.converterPessoa}"
                                        completeMethod="#{chamadoControle.completePessoa}" disabled="true" requiredMessage="O campo Estado deve ser informado!" required="true" />

                        <p:commandLink id="equip" value="Equipamento:" ajax="true"/> 
                        <p:autoComplete id="equip1" onchange="" style="width:600px" dropdown="true"
                                        multiple="false" forceSelection="true" var="obj"
                                        itemLabel="#{obj.tipo}" itemValue="#{obj}"
                                        value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.equipamento}"
                                        converter="#{chamadoControle.converterEquipamento}"
                                        completeMethod="#{chamadoControle.completeEquipamento}" disabled="true" requiredMessage="O campo Estado deve ser informado!" required="true" />

                        <h:outputLabel value="Problema:" for="problema" />
                        <p:inputText size="30" id="problema"  maxlength="60" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.problema}" disabled="true" title="Problema" required="true" requiredMessage="O nome da cidade é obrigatório!"/>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Observações:" for="observacoes" />
                        <p:inputTextarea   maxlength="60" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.observacoes}" disabled="true" title="Observações:" required="true" requiredMessage="O nome da cidade é obrigatório!"/>

                        <p:commandLink id="peca" value="Peças:" ajax="true"/> 
                        <p:autoComplete id="peca1"  style="width:600px" dropdown="true"
                                        multiple="false" forceSelection="true" var="obj"
                                        itemLabel="#{obj.descricao}"  itemValue="#{obj}"
                                        value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.peca}"
                                        converter="#{chamadoControle.converterPeca}"
                                        completeMethod="#{chamadoControle.completePeca}"  requiredMessage="O campo peça é Obrigatório!" required="true" >


                        </p:autoComplete>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Valor da Peça:" for="orcamento" />
                        <p:inputText size="4"  disabled="true" id="valorPeca" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.peca.valor}" title="Valor da Peça" />

                        <p:commandLink id="servico" value="Serviços:" ajax="true"/> 
                        <p:autoComplete id="servico1"  style="width:600px" dropdown="true"
                                        multiple="false" forceSelection="true" var="obj"
                                        itemLabel="#{obj.descricao}" itemValue="#{obj}"
                                        value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.servico}"
                                        converter="#{chamadoControle.converterServico}"
                                        completeMethod="#{chamadoControle.completeServico}" requiredMessage="O campo serviço é Obrigatório!" required="true" >


                        </p:autoComplete>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Valor do Serviço:" for="orcamento" />
                            <p:inputText size="4" disabled="true" id="valor" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.peca.valor}" title="Valor da Peça" />

                             <h:outputLabel value="Valor Total" for="orcamento" />
                            <p:inputText size="4" disabled="true" id="valortotal" value="" title="Valor Total" />

                            <h:outputLabel value="Observações sobre Peças:" for="obspeca" />
                        <p:inputTextarea  id="obspeca" maxlength="60" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.obspeca}" cols="30"/>


                        <h:outputLabel value="Data do Orçamento:" for="dataOrcamento" />
                        <p:calendar size="14" id="orcamento" value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.dataOrcamento}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" readonly="true" 
                                    required="true" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" locale="pt_BR" requiredMessage="O campo data do orçamento é Obrigatório!"/>

                        <h:outputLabel value="Status do Orçamento:" for="status" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{chamadoControle.objeto.status}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aguardando Aprovação" itemValue="Aguardando Aprovação" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Não Aprovado" itemValue="Orçamento não Aprovado" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Aprovado" itemValue="Orçamento Aprovado" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <div align="center">
                                <p:commandButton value="testevalorpeca" onclick="valorPeca();" ajax="false" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" action="#{chamadoControle.cancelar()}" immediate="true" ajax="false" />
                                <p:commandButton action="#{chamadoControle.gravar()}" value="Salvar" ajax="false" />

                            </div>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <p:watermark for="peca1" value="Obrigatório"/>
                    <p:watermark for="obspeca" value="Opcional"/>
                    <p:watermark for="valor" value="R$"/>
                    <p:watermark for="orcamento" value="Obrigatório"/>
                </h:form>
            </f:view>

        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Necessito pegar o valor de cada autocomplete e preencher no no outro campo, porém ele só fica o valor do item defaut, quando eu troco o valor não muda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual outro campo que é pra ser preenchido ?